# What is a right way of using ctypes to call a cpp function with reference parameters in dll/so?

Tags: python, ctypes

I know it is not appropriate to call a cpp function in dll/so, eg. `int foo(int&)`, by `ctpyes`, due to there is no equivalent concept of reference variable in `c`. But i'd like to show a demo of do this, and i'm really confused about python's behavior(version 3.7).

Basically, i have a dll from other people, and i believe it is built by vs c++ and exported using `extern "C"`. There are some interfaces in the dll take a form of `int foo(int&)`. When i use python, i need a `ctypes` layer to wrap it up. For example,

```
int foo(int&)
```

is translated to (_foo is loaded by `ctypes`)

```
_foo.argtypes = [POINTER(c_int)]
_foo.restype = c_int
```

and i call `foo` in python like

```
i = c_int(1)
_foo(i)
```

and IT WORKS.
I further test with a demo in linux with following code,

demo.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" int foo(int&);

int foo(int& i)
{
    printf("foo is called.\n");
    printf("Got i: %d\n", i);
    i += 10;
    printf("Set i: %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

build

```
g++ -Wall -fPIC -c demo.cpp
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libdemo.so.1 -o libdemo.so demo.o
```

So, a `libdemo.so` is built.

demo.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from ctypes import CDLL, c_int,POINTER

l = CDLL("libdemo.so")

_foo = l.foo

_foo.argtypes = [POINTER(c_int)]
_foo.restype = c_int
def foo(i):
    print("Input: i",i)
    _i = c_int(i)
    r = _foo(_i)
    i = _i.value
    print("Output: i", i)

foo(1)
```

if i run demo.py

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./demo.py
```

it will work fine, and give me the right answer, i.e.

```
Input: i 1
foo is called.
Got i: 1
Set i: 11
Output: i 11
```

And, if i passed the `i` by `byref`, changed the `demo.py` as

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from ctypes import CDLL, c_int,POINTER,byref

l = CDLL("libdemo.so")

_demo = l.demo

_demo.argtypes = [PONTER(c_int)]
_demo.restype = c_int
def demo(i):
    print("Input: i",i)
    _i = c_int(i)
    r = _demo(byref(_i))  # calling by byref
    i = _i.value
    print("Output: i", i)

demo(1)
```

it still works as it is, and output the same.

So, what is happen under the hood? Why the above two versions `demo.py` have the same output? Can i depend on such a feature to use `ctpyes` to call cpp functions which could have parameters by reference?